# Prove limit of the function $g = f-xf'$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function and $g :[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x) = f(x) -xf'(x)$. Prove that $f$ is convex if and only if $g$ is non increasing (and this is easy, just calculate $g'(x)$).

$\textbf{Where I'm stuck is }$

prove that if $f$ is convex and if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = \infty$$ than $$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = - \infty$$

$\textbf{My attempt}$

Assume for a moment that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) \neq - \infty$$ Then $g$ has a finite limite, since it's a decreasing function. So we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf''(x) = 0$. I can't go on from this point.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is bounded below. Then $\int_1^{x} f''(t)dt \leq \int_1^{x} tf''(t)dt=\int_1^{x} -g'(t)dt=g(1)-g(x)$. It follows that $f'(x)-f'(1)$ is bounded above which is a contradiction.